# My program doesn't draw/render what it has to

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I'm reading a book about game development: Beginning Java Game Development with LibGDX.

There was a class named `CheesePlease3` that I copied from the book, it presented the `Stage` class, and `Actor` class, I had to make a subclass from the `Actor` class, named `BaseActor`.

I did everything correctly, basically copy-pasted the whole thing, and it doesn't draw any object.

So my question is why? What is wrong?

Maybe the code itself a little bit long but easy to read.

Here is the `CheesePlease3` class:

```
public class CheesePlease3 extends Game {

public Stage mainStage;
private BaseActor mouse;
private BaseActor cheese;
private BaseActor floor;
private BaseActor winText;

@Override
public void create () {

    mainStage = new Stage();

    floor = new BaseActor();
    floor.setTexture(new Texture("floor.png"));
    floor.setPosition(0, 0);
    mainStage.addActor(floor);

    cheese = new BaseActor();
    cheese.setTexture(new Texture("cheese.png"));
    cheese.setPosition(300, 300);
    mainStage.addActor(cheese);

    mouse = new BaseActor();
    mouse.setTexture(new Texture("mouse.png"));
    mouse.setPosition(200, 200);
    mainStage.addActor(mouse);

    winText = new BaseActor();
    winText.setTexture(new Texture("youWon.png"));
    winText.setPosition(150, 150);
    winText.setVisible(false);
    mainStage.addActor(winText);

}

@Override
public void render(){
    // process input

    mouse.velocityX = 0;
    mouse.velocityY = 0;

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        mouse.velocityX -= 100;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        mouse.velocityX += 100;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        mouse.velocityY -= 100;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
        mouse.velocityY += 100;

    // update

    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    mainStage.act(dt);

    // check win condition: Mouse must be overlapping cheese

    Rectangle mouseRectangle = mouse.getBoundingRectangle();
    Rectangle cheeseRectangle = cheese.getBoundingRectangle();

    if (mouseRectangle.contains(cheeseRectangle))
        winText.setVisible(true);

    // draw graphics

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    mainStage.draw();

}
```

And here is the BaseActor class:

```
public class BaseActor extends Actor {

public TextureRegion region;
public Rectangle boundary;
public float velocityX;
public float velocityY;

public BaseActor(){
    super();
    region = new TextureRegion();
    boundary = new Rectangle();
    velocityX = 0;
    velocityY = 0;
}

public void setTexture (Texture t){
    int w = t.getWidth();
    int h = t.getHeight();
    setWidth(w);
    setHeight(h);
    region.setRegion(t);
}

public Rectangle getBoundingRectangle(){
    return boundary.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}

@Override
public void act (float dt){
    super.act(dt);
    moveBy(velocityX * dt, velocityY * dt);
}

public void drawBatch (Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    Color c = getColor();
    batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a);

    if (isVisible())
        batch.draw(region, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
                   getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
}
```

And here is the DesktopLauncher:

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    new LwjglApplication(new CheesePlease3(), config);
    config.title = "Mouse - Cheese";
}
```

Comment: Where is your `main`?  Where does the code actually get executed?

Comment: It is in the DesktopLauncher class, it is the same that LibGDX provide. I've edited the question, so it provides the main method too.

Comment: You are calling `CheesePlease4` in there, not `CheesePlease3`?

Comment: Yeah it is a new task but those two are the same, I didn't want to start a new task until this one works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BaseActor has to override the `draw` method.
I assume the `drawBatch` method should be renamed to `draw`.

Ps.:
The movement for up and down is inverted.

Comment: Thank you indeed. It was the drawBatch method, also thanks for pointing out the movement.